# Run Javascript script from ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, visual-studio-cordova

I want to call a JS Script in Ajax response. What it does is pass the `document.getElementById` script to the Ajax responseText.

The current code returns me this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

This is done with Visual Studio Cordova..

Ajax:

```
$("#loginBtn").click(function() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.write(this.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.sampleee.esy.es/login.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&" + "password=" + password);
});
```

PHP:

```
if($count == 1){
   echo "document.getElementById('alertBox').innerHTML = 'Login Success!';
        document.getElementById('alertBox').className = 'alert alert-success';
        document.getElementById('alertBox').style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = '../html/dashboard.html';
            }, 1000);
        ";
}else{
       echo "document.getElementById('alertBox').innerHTML = 'Invalid login details'; 
        document.getElementById('alertBox').className = 'alert alert-danger';
        document.getElementById('alertBox').style.display = 'block';
        ";
}
```

Comment: The element with id `alertBox` is not in the DOM at the time you access it and try to set `innerHTML`.  Are you appending it somewhere before the ajax call? if not you need to do that first.

Comment: I think it would be easier to have the PHP just return a success/failure indicator and have the existing Ajax JS test that return value and display the appropriate message with the appropriate class. Also, given that you are using jQuery, why are you hand-coding your own Ajax call rather than using `$.ajax()`?

Comment: you need to create a script element, then add the text from the response, then add the element to the DOM

Comment: Well, you could do it, but it is a dangerous thing since you basically need to eval it.. And you should never use document.write after the page loads.

Comment: The problem is `document.write()` wipes out everything in the page when it is run after the initial page load....then you can't use getElementById...there are no more elements left

Comment: I'm really sorry guys, I'm very new to this ajax thingy. Thanks for all your help! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by a small change, you just have to write JS code in the AJAX success that you wrote in your PHP page. In the PHP page, there is no `alertBox` element, that's why the error occurred.

Your JS code will be like this:

```
$("#loginBtn").click(function() {
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if(this.responseText=="success"){
        document.getElementById('alertBox').innerHTML = 'Login Success!';
        document.getElementById('alertBox').className = 'alert alert-success';
        document.getElementById('alertBox').style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = '../html/dashboard.html';
        }, 1000);
        }elseif(this.responseText=="error"){
         document.getElementById('alertBox').innerHTML = 'Invalid login details'; 
    document.getElementById('alertBox').className = 'alert alert-danger';
    document.getElementById('alertBox').style.display = 'block'
         }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.sampleee.esy.es/login.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&" + "password=" + password);
  });
```

And PHP code like:

```
 if($count == 1){
 echo "success";
 }else{
   echo "error";
  }
```

Comment: Why couldn't have I thought of this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you get that error because the thing you're trying to change is not on the page when you look for it.

What you need to do is, do not write javascript with PHP. You return something like an int from php and then use that to decide what the javascript does.

You have the html on the page and just change the content inside it.

```js
$("#loginBtn").click(function() {
      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

          var str = this.responseText; //you may need to trim whitespace
          var alert = document.getElementById('alertBox');
          if (str.trim() == 1) {

               alert.innerHTML = 'Login Success!';
               alert.className = 'alert alert-success';
               alert.style.display = 'block';
               setTimeout(function() {
                 window.location.href = '../html/dashboard.html';
               }, 1000);

          } 
          else {

               alert.innerHTML = 'Invalid login details';
               alert.className = 'alert alert-danger';
               alert.style.display = 'block';

          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.sampleee.esy.es/login.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&" + "password=" + password);
      });
```

```html
<div id="alertbox"></div>
```

PHP Code:

```
 if($count == 1){
      echo 1;
}
else{
      echo 0;
}
```

Comment: should trim the response when using strings in php...it's notorious for adding extra whitespace

Comment: Done, but I have never had that problem though.

Comment: not usually a problem if you aren't needing to do response comparison

Comment: I do this kind of comparison a lot. May have to do with output buffering and other factors though too.

Answer (score 0):

Use eval like below

```
$("#loginBtn").click(function() {
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var fun = eval(this.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.sampleee.esy.es/login.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&" + "password=" + password);
```

});